# unixODBC: Cannot load libmaodbc.so

Tags: linux, arm, shared-library, mariadb, odbc

I'm working on an embedded platform and I am trying to access a MariaDB through unixODBC.
Trying to test the connection with isql I get the response:

```
isql -v mydsn myuser mypw
[01000][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/lib/libmaodbc.so' : file not found
```

The file /usr/lib/libmaodbc.so exists:

```
ls -la /usr/lib/libmaodbc.so
-r-xr-xr-x    1 root     root        403952 Sep  1 00:00 /usr/lib/libmaodbc.so
```

So I figured a dependency must be missing.

```
readelf -d /usr/lib/libmaodbc.so 

Dynamic section at offset 0x4fb54 contains 30 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libodbcinst.so.2]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libm.so.6]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [ld-linux-armhf.so.3]
 0x0000000e (SONAME)                     Library soname: [libmaodbc.so]
[...]
```

I repeated the check - all four dependencies exist.

Next I wrote a test program, which tries to load the shared objects:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <dlfcn.h>

void tryLoadSo(const std::string& path) {
    void* so = dlopen(path.c_str(), RTLD_NOW);
    if(so) {
        std::cout << "Loaded " << path << "!" << std::endl;
        dlclose(so);
    } else {
        std::cout << "Failed to load " << path << "!" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    tryLoadSo("/usr/lib/libmaodbc.so");
    tryLoadSo("/usr/lib/libodbcinst.so.2");
    tryLoadSo("/usr/lib/libm.so.6");
    tryLoadSo("/usr/lib/libc.so.6");
    tryLoadSo("/usr/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3");
}
```

Output:

```
Failed to load /usr/lib/libmaodbc.so!
Loaded /usr/lib/libodbcinst.so.2!
Loaded /usr/lib/libm.so.6!
Loaded /usr/lib/libc.so.6!
Loaded /usr/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3!
```

Thus all the dependencies can be loaded, but libmaodbc cannot.

Is the shared object not configured for the correct plattform? Yes, it is. I compared it to libodbcinst.so.2 to make sure:

```
readelf -h /usr/lib/libmaodbc.so 
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              DYN (Shared object file)
  Machine:                           ARM
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x9a58
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          402952 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x5000400, Version5 EABI, hard-float ABI
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         7
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         25
  Section header string table index: 24

readelf -h /usr/lib/libodbcinst.so.2
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              DYN (Shared object file)
  Machine:                           ARM
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x1e60
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          53528 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x5000400, Version5 EABI, hard-float ABI
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         6
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         24
  Section header string table index: 23
```

What could be going wrong? Why won't libmaodbc.so load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

libmaodbc.so was linked statically against libmariadb.so.3. Now I linked libmariadb.so.3 dynamically and it worked.

No idea if a bad/unmatching library was linked or some other settings for linking were not correct (maybe something not ok in CMakeLists.txt?). So I still don't understand the root cause. But the symptom is fixed.